# Troubleshooting ADB Command Recognition Issues on Windows with USB Debugging Enabled

Tags: adb, usb-debugging

[image] The ADB command is not recognized despite enabling USB debugging on my Android device.

1. Can you help me diagnose why the ADB command is not recognized despite enabling USB debugging on my Android device?
2. What steps can I take to troubleshoot issues with ADB on Windows?
3. Are there any common reasons ADB might not work, even after enabling USB debugging?

Comment: It's touchy on new android devices you have to have the bug icon in the display.

What android device are you using?

Also what are the error messages?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the commands you execute and the output (include is as text not screenshot). Your first point read like the command `adb` is not present on your PC or not in PATH. If adb command is available or not has nothing to do with the Android developer settings on your phone. If you have a working adb then it can be executed even without a device attached. So at least `adb devices` should work but will not show any devices.